# Using jQuery noConflict yet results in "Uncaught TypeError"

Tags: jquery, vticker

I'm using [vticker](https://github.com/richhollis/vticker/) inside a wordpress blog. Page source is very messy, but I can confirm jQuery is running!! Neither `noConflict` nor `jQuery()` instead of `$` works out of error.

[image]

Clues to finding a solution are really appreciated.

*Code*:

```
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(function($){
    j$('ul.site-wide-stream.swa-activity-list').vTicker({ 
        speed: 500,
        pause: 3000,
        animation: 'fade',
        mousePause: false,
        showItems: 6
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post relevant code, it´s close to impossible to figure out whats going on by squinting at a screendump.

Comment: Uhm, you're getting `undefined is not a function`, it has nothing to do with noConflict, which you shouldn't be using as Wordpress is already in noConflict mode, it's because you're calling `vTicker` and it doesn't exist.

Comment: @papirtiger You could open the image in a new window to see the original size, however I added the code.

Comment: @adeneo How would it possible! I included vticker js file and it loads perfectly!